# Exclude disabled checkboxes when using Select All

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have checkboxes with labels in table. I have added one checkbox outside the table "Select All" with id "chkbox". Now the below code is working fine. It is
Selecting and Deselecting all the checkboxes in the table. Now there are some pages where some checkboxes are disabled due to business logic. I want these checkboxes should not be affected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = jQuery.noConflict();
s(document).ready(function() {
    s('#chkbox').change(function() {
        var all = s('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        if (this.checked) {
            all.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            all.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `s('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with [`:disabled`](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector.

```
var all = $('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:disabled)');
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will not select the disabled checkboxes

```js
$('#selectAll').change(function() {
  $(':checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />Select All

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
</ul>
```

---

You can also use [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector.

```
$('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')
```

```js
$('#selectAll').change(function() {
  $(':checkbox:enabled').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /> Select All

<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />Not disabled</li>
</ul>
```

**Note that: `:enabled` == `:not(:disabled)`**

Comment: anything wrong with `s('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')`?