# How to make disabled checkboxes not checked using table with td outputs from PHP, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I have researched is the following links:

[Exclude disabled checkboxes when using Select All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333044/exclude-disabled-checkboxes-when-using-select-all)

[Select all checkbox elements except disabled ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448442/select-all-checkbox-elements-except-disabled-ones#comment23594026_16448442)

[jquery selector for all checked checkboxes that are not disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358231/jquery-selector-for-all-checked-checkboxes-that-are-not-disabled)

All of this did not work to my code, I tried to do it step by step by removing and adding class name or id names but still it did not work. My UI has dataTable inside my form and inside dataTable I have a checkbox from a column that will select all, and it is working, another thing of what I did is when the data is passed to my database, the checkbox will be disabled, the problem is the `.prop()` method does not work and I don't know why and searched a few questions regarding this, checkboxes that were disabled are still checkable. My goal is to not include the disable checkbox when I will select all.

My code

```js
$("#select_all").on('click', function() {
    $('#dataTables').DataTable()
        .column(3)
        .nodes()
        .to$()
        .find('input[type=checkbox]')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('#select_all').change(function() {
  $(':checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Control No. </th>
          <th> Tools Specification </th>
          <th> Supplier </th>
          <th>
            <center>
              Select Tools
              <input type="checkbox" id="select_all">
            </center>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php
        $con->next_result();
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL GetDisplayedToolsRegistration()"); ?>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
          {
          if($row['ID'] == $row['tools_req_id'])
          {

             echo '<tr>';
             echo "<td>" .$row['reg_input'] . "</td>";  
             echo '<td>' .$row['reg_tools_spec']. '</td>';  
             echo '<td>' .$row['reg_supplier']. '</td>';  
        ?>
          <td>
            <center>
              <input name="chk[]" id="is_checked_req" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];? 
              >" disabled>
            </center>
          </td>
          <?php
          
          }                                                                  
          else
          {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo "<td>" .$row['reg_input'] . "</td>";  
          echo '<td>' .$row['reg_tools_spec']. '</td>';  
          echo '<td>' .$row['reg_supplier']. '</td>'; 
                                                                        
          ?>
          <td>
            <center>
              <input name="chk[]" id="is_checked_req" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];? 
              >">
            </center>
          </td>
          <?php                                                                
           
           }     
          
          echo '</tr>'; 
          
          }
          ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my analyzations after for how many hours I have an answer to my own question. The first problem that I recognized/analyzed is I am using two functions on calling my elements using by ID's in this code `$("#select_all").on('click', function() {});` when it should not be like that, only one ID and it should be another class name you named. Second problem that I did not notice and solved while reshuffling code is this `.find('input[type=checkbox]')` where I should just recode this and add `:enabled`. So conclusion of my answer through code is this.

JS Code for my checkbox where it will select all checkboxes

```
$("#select_all").on('click', function() {
$('#dataTables').DataTable()
    .column(3)
    .nodes()
    .to$()
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')
    .prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```